# text-shadow applied to Google Web Fonts in iOS browsers

Tags: css, ios6

I'm getting a problem on iOS with the standard text-shadow effect applied to Google Web Fonts. The font appears doubled with a shadow behind two layers of the font-color. It's most pronounced on my non-retina ipad mini. I've seen no such behavior on my laptop browsers.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Here's a demonstration easy to type into an ios browser: [Link](http://crosby-generic-staging.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

For now, I just have a * selector stripping text-shadow off all text on smaller screen sizes using media queries. maybe there's a better patch on the problem.

**Here's a screenshot from an iPad mini:**
[image: photo.jpg]

**Screen shot**
[image: Screen shot (iPhone 4S)]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the effect you're referencing, many users won't have access to an iOS device.

Comment: This is intriguing. I'm able to reproduce it on another site. Offset seems to be 2x or 4x for iOS

Answer (score 1):

Searching didn't get me anywhere, it might be related to the percentage offset compared to the text size (when you scale the text from 32px to 20px the 2px is a bigger fraction). You could try to experiment with using % in stead of px, or just add the following.

In your responsive CSS, add

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    text-shadow: text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px;
}
```

This renders much nicer on the smaller text

**EDIT**
I see that you have updated your question with a screenshot. This offset render bug might be the same as [described here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10449/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left-/p1). The problem seems to be that you are using `font-weight: bold` and that Mobile Safari can't handle it. The solution seems to be to set it to normal.

```
/*reset for mobile browsers */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```